# Null check operator used on a null value in flutter with firebase firestore . How to solve this error?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i try to fetch data from firebase database but "Null check operator used on a null value" error. I have already check the models but those are also no errors.

**this is the database structure.**

[image]

my code

```
 Future<Map<ClientInfo, List<Hospital>>> getUserProfiles({
      required String googleAuthId,
    }) async {
      // Get a reference to the "RegisteredClientInfo" collection
      CollectionReference registeredClientInfoRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(googleAuthId)
          .collection("RegisteredClientInfo");
      print('googleAuthId 2: $googleAuthId');
      // Map client info to hospitals
      final Map<ClientInfo, List<Hospital>> clientHospitalMap = {};
      final querySnapshot = await registeredClientInfoRef.get();
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        // Create ClientInfo object
        print('Before: final clientInfo = ClientInfo.fromSnapshot(doc);');
        final clientInfo = ClientInfo.fromSnapshot(doc);
        print('After: final clientInfo = ClientInfo.fromSnapshot(doc);');
  
        // Fetch all hospitals for the client
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshotProfiles =
        await registeredClientInfoRef
            .doc(doc.id)
            .collection('Profiles')
            .get();
        print('doc.id 2: ${doc.id}');
        print('ClientInfo check 2: $clientInfo');
        // Create list of hospitals for the client
        final List<Hospital> hospitals = querySnapshotProfiles.docs
            .map((doc) => Hospital.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
        print('Hospitals: $hospitals');
        // Add the list of hospitals to the client's info in the map
        clientHospitalMap[clientInfo] = hospitals;
      }
      print('Hospitals11: $clientHospitalMap');
      return clientHospitalMap;
    }
```

console
[image]

I printed the clientinfo and hospital details but

```
ClientInfo check 2: Instance of 'ClientInfo'
I/flutter (11797): Hospitals: [Instance of 'Hospital']
I/flutter (11797): Before: final clientInfo = ClientInfo.fromSnapshot(doc);
I/flutter (11797): After: final clientInfo = ClientInfo.fromSnapshot(doc);
```

i cannot understand what is the issue  and how to solve this null error..

```
Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: FutureBuilder<Map<ClientInfo, List<Hospital>>>(
            future:
                FirebaseManager().getUserProfiles(googleAuthId: gSignClientId),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                List<ClientInfo> selectedClientInfo =
                    snapshot.data!.keys.toList();
                if (selectedClientInfo.isEmpty) {
                  return const Center(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        "No profile found. Please add profiles by pressing 'Search Profiles'.",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  ));
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: selectedClientInfo.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, indexProfile) {
                    final hospitalsInProfile =
                        snapshot.data![selectedClientInfo[indexProfile]]!;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: hospitalsInProfile.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final hospital = hospitalsInProfile[index];
                        return Stack(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: indexProfile ==
                                          (selectedClientInfo.length - 1)
                                      ? 70.0
                                      : 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  VetPulzConstants.clientInfo =
                                      selectedClientInfo[indexProfile];
                                  final clientID =
                                      selectedClientInfo[indexProfile]
                                          .id
                                          .toString();
                                  VetPulzConstants.CLIENT_ID = clientID;
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            MainHomeScreen(
                                          selectedHospital: hospital,
                                          clientID: clientID,
                                        ),
                                      ));
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                  child: Card(
                                    elevation: 0,
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color:
                                            VetPulzConstants.vetpulzCardColor,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            30.0), // increase value here
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                            spreadRadius: 2,
                                            blurRadius: 2,
                                            offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            selectedClientInfo[indexProfile]
                                                .name,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                                          Text(selectedClientInfo[indexProfile]
                                              .clientID),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                          const Divider(),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.email,
                                                color: VetPulzConstants
                                                    .vetpulzTitleColor,
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(selectedClientInfo[
                                                      indexProfile]
                                                  .email),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.phone,
                                                color: VetPulzConstants
                                                    .vetpulzTitleColor,
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(selectedClientInfo[
                                                      indexProfile]
                                                  .mobileNumber),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.local_hospital,
                                                color: VetPulzConstants
                                                    .vetpulzTitleColor,
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(hospital.hospitalName),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: 10,
                              right: 10,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  showDeleteConfirmationDialog(context,
                                      () async {
                                    EasyLoading.show(
                                        status: "Deleting",
                                        maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.black);
                                    final clientID =
                                        selectedClientInfo[indexProfile]
                                            .clientID
                                            .toString();
                                    await FirebaseManager()
                                        .deleteUserProfile(
                                            gSignClientId, clientID)
                                        .then((value) {
                                      EasyLoading.dismiss();
                                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                  ProfileSelectionScreen(
                                                    gSignClientId:
                                                        gSignClientId,
                                                  )),
                                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                                    });
                                  });
                                },
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

i can see that the function you wrote fetch hospitals and stores into a map, but the null getting printed is from different code, can you provide that also so that we can identify the issue, as this function is storing the values correctly.